# How to add a default Default.aspx to a ASP.NET Web Application Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am working with Visual Studio 2015.

I created a new **ASP.NET Web Application** project. 
Then get a screen to ***Select a template***. I selected **Empty**.

The Project named **WebApplication1** is created. It has 2 files

1. `packages.config`
2. `Web.config`

But it does not have `Default.aspx`. I remember older version of Visual Studio used to create `Default.aspx` automatically. So how can I add it?

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't select `Empty` and you should select new `Web Application` then remove the files that you don't want.. this is extremely basic also are you familiar with how to use the `Right Mouse Button` click and checkout all the options pay attention to `New Item vs Existing Item` `-1` if you are not familiar with how to use `Visual Studio IDE` there are MSDN documentation on this or `YouTube` video's out there that can walk you through step by step good is your best friend if you use it properly..

Comment: In the Templates the options available were: `Empty`, `Web Forms`, `MVC`, `Web API` and `Single Page Application`. I tried the right-click mouse and see all the options of `New Item` but there were none saying `Default.aspx`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow these simple steps:

1. Right click your project
2. Click on New
3. Select Web Form
4. Write Default.aspx as name

Answer (score 2):

An empty template now means that you want project with no server/client file. If you want to add a Default.aspx, that means that you would like to create a Webform project. You can just:

Right click on the WebApplication1 project -> click on Add  -> New Item -> Then select Web Form (change the name from WebForm1.aspx to Default.aspx)