# How to add a default create .aspxFile to a ASP.NET Web Application Project?

Tags: asp.net

I am working with Visual Studio 2019.

I created a new ASP.NET Web Application project. I selected Empty. Then I click

> WebApplication1 project -> click on Add -> New Item ->

But I can't find Web Form? Does anyone know?

Comment: Can you add a folder and then try to add new item.

Comment: I just add a folder but i can't find web form :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34008926/6923146

Comment: its there, maybe you do not have install it. You start by creating the project - and all its there